# Override a file using git checkout does not warn about losing changes

Tags: git, git-checkout

I recently found out I could override a file from my tracking remote branch doing the next : "git checkout origin/remoteBranchName nameFile.txt". But I have some questions:

1. Having changes in this file not commited, executing the command does not warn about losing changes and when switching to other branch it does. Why?
2. I tried to override using hard reset but I think you cannot do it with one file. Why?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I tried to override using hard reset but I think you cannot do it with
> one file. Why?

```
 $ git reset -- file.c
```

According to https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reset

> Reset a single file in the index
>
> Suppose you have added a file to your
> index, but later decide you do not want to add it to your commit. You
> can remove the file from the index while keeping your changes with git
> reset.
>
> $ git reset -- frotz.c                       (1)
>
> $ git commit -m "Commit files in index"      (2)
>
> $ git add frotz.c                            (3)
>
> 1. This removes the file from the index while keeping it in the working directory.
> 2. This commits all other changes in the index.
> 3. Adds the file to the index again.